# How do large merchant resellers process payments and payouts?

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment, payment-processing

I am looking for information on how large resellers **collect payments** and **pay** the **people** who sell on their site. (e.g. [Redbubble.com](http://redbubble.com), a company that pays artists a commission for their work)

Specifically, I am looking for different solutions that cover a few key functions at minimal cost (like Paypal fees)

- Ability to **take payment** from credit cards and paypal (others a benefit)
- **Track sales** for each merchant as payments are processing
- Collect payments in **central account**
- **Payout** all processed payments on a **monthly basis**

P.S. I imagine there are a few ways to do this, I am hoping to gain some insight on what solutions have been **proven**.

P.P.S. **This is not a technology specific question.** Whatever APIs or third party solutions you know of are fair game.

Thanks for your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Try PayPal adaptive payments.

[Paypal Adaptive payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

You can also try Stripe to collect funds to one account and to trasfer them to third party acccounts but this only works in the US.

[Stripe Payments](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) and that would allow you to split the payments up among multiple receivers in a single transaction in real-time.  If you go that route the API calls that you'd be interested in are...

- [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) - This setups the actual payment and the receivers on the payment.
- [SetPaymentOptions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) - This allows you to provide more details like items, shipping, etc.
- [ExecutePayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/) - This actually processes the payment in the system after it's been setup with the previous calls.
- [PaymentDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/) - This obtains details about a completed transaction.
- [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) (possibly) - This allows you to get a Preapproval key for a user that will allow you to trigger payments on that users behalf at any time in the future with the use of the preapproval key.
- [PreapprovalDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PreapprovalDetails_API_Operation/) (if you use preapprovals) - This obtains details about an active preapproval profile.

To get all of that working in the live environment you'll need to submit an application through your [PayPal developer account](http://developer.paypal.com) to obtain a Classic API App ID.  For development on the sandbox there is a global App ID that can be used.

Another option would be to take payments on your site using any PayPal product like [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wps), [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec), [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wpp), etc. and have all the money come to your account, and then use the Pay API to distribute those funds out to people accordingly.  This could be automated with an [IPN solution](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) and possibly the use of a CRON job on your server.

This is the method I like to use, and I typically go with a full Payments Pro / Express Checkout integration for payments on my site and then I distribute via the Pay API within an IPN solution or CRON job like I mentioned.